# How do I run php custom script on magento2

Tags: magento2, nginx, script

I wanted to add custom php script to magento2 root folder and run from the browser.I tried to add it in magento2 root folder but it redirects to 404 page.

I also tried to add it in pub folder but no success.

Also cleared cache and generation.

I am running magento2 on nginx server

Comment: Sounds strange. I created test.php script in magento2 root dir, then I just call it from browser http://%magento-base-url%/test.php and it's work.

Comment: I am running magento2 on nginx server

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using nginx configuration that comes with magento you need to put a file inside `pub` folder to allow access to it from the browser as pub is the document root of the vhost. Magento root dir is one level up.

Second of all default config for nginx allows only to access `index.php`, `get.php`, `static.php`, `report.php`, `404.php` and `503.php` files. Any other are not processed by the php. You can see this in line with `location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {` in nginx.conf.sample. If you are not using it check your config for similar rule.

To allow another file to be accessible from browser simple add another name after 503 or change entire brackets with `location ~* \.php$ {`

Comment: Do i need restart nginxafter change ?

Comment: Yes, any change to vhost requires at least reload.

Comment: Thanks man its working

Answer (score 21):

For example, to get a product name by the custom script

> **Example 1:**

Create `test.php` at the root of Magento `var/www/html/magento2/test.php`

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$id = 1;
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);

echo $product->getName();
```

**You can run script `test.php` by**

http://127.0.0.1/magento2/test.php

> **Example 2:**

**Step 1: create index.php at the root of Magento 2**

`var/www/html/magento2/test/index.php`

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('customScript');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**Step 2: create customScript.php**

`/var/www/html/magento2/test/customScript.php`

```
<?php
class customScript
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {
    public function launch()
    {
        $this->_state->setAreaCode('frontend'); //Set area code 'frontend' or 'adminhtml
        $id = 12;
        $_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
        
        echo $_product->getName();

        return $this->_response;
    }
 
    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
 
}
```

Now you can run this custom script by

http://127.0.0.1/magento2/test/

[image]

Comment: I got an error 'class customScript not found' so I added 'require './customScript.php' before '$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('customScript');' and that worked.

Comment: I'm getting page not found error

Comment: @ravisoni, that means you did something wrong. Make sure to create folder /test/ and two files index.php and other one customScript.php

Comment: @Zankar, you need to place your customScript.php file in the same folder (subfolder from sitedir) as index.php file. From your code `./customScript.php` I can see that your customScript.php is one level up from index.php

Comment: @electroid in my case the `customScript.php` file is in the same directory as `index.php`. If I was including it from a folder one level up I would do `../customScript.php` (note the two dots)

Comment: Am getting 404, I created index.php & custom.php under test folder

Comment: how to redirect to controller from this file? ex: checkout/cart

Comment: @jafarpinjar Please refer this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150615/how-to-write-redirect-script-from-magento2-phtml-page-to-another-phtml-page

Comment: @PrincePatel, I need to redirect to custom controller with param value? can u update me pls

Answer (score 6):

If you want to allow **more than one** php script to be executable like I need (import.php for ERP import product, stock.php for update the inventory with my ERP etc...) :

- create a new directory `scripts` in the `/pub` folder
- edit your `magento` vhost and add lines under `##Allow pub/srcipts/ folder to execute php custom`

---

```
     listen 80;
     server_name example.com www.example.com;

     set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento2;
     include /var/www/html/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;

     ## Allow pub/srcipts/ folder to execute php custom
     location /scripts/ {
        location ~* \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
                fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

                fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
        }
     }
```

With this you can now run your scripts by accessing them at :

```
http://www.example.com/scripts/your_custom_code.php
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.