# How to use Mage::getModel() on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.4

I need to convert my following Mage::getModel() from Magento1 to Magento2

```
$cart_api = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart_api');
$quoteId = $cart_api->create($storeObject->getStoreId());
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

$convertQuoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote');

$storeObject = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(1);
```

So anyone let me know the correct method for Magento2.

Answer (score 1):

Override constructor in your Model class and add your model class as dependency.

```
protected $_modelObj;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Vendor\Example\Model\Model $modelObj,
    ...
) {
      ...
      $this->modelObj = $modelObj;
      ...
}

function someMetod() {
    $model =  $this->modelObj->create();
}
```

There are thousands of examples you can find in google for same. Also you can check core files how it is implemented.

Adding here one specific answer for your question:

```
protected $_quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
) {
    $this->_quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
```

Then in your class you can do:

```
$this->_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
```

For using it in your custom class, check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97196/how-do-i-run-php-custom-script-on-magento2) link!

Hope this helps!

```
<?php

namespace Yourcompany\<yourmodule>\Helper {

/**
 * Customer data helper
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterfaceFactory $customerRepositoryFactory) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepositoryFactory->create();
    }

    public LoadCustomerById($customerId) {
         $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
         return $customer;
    } 

}
```

Same way you can add functions for getting product detail and use these in your module controller. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Sukumar, direct use of $objectManager is not accepted as standard way of implementation. It should be done via class constructor.

Comment: I need to get all the above values in my custom php file placed in magento 2 root. So let me know how to do this for my above code?

Comment: @Pallavi Mage::getModel is accepted? I am only saying what are the code for getModel and getSingleton in magento2. So Please read the question carefully as I also know use of objectManager anywhere directly is not good practice.

Comment: How can I use it in my Custom class?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, My comment was not intended to offend you in any ways. However If you felt so, I apologize. My only intention was to tell the correct way of implementation, that's it. hope you understand!

Comment: This is my exact need : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233074/convert-custom-order-create-functions-from-magento-1-to-magento-2

Comment: @Pallavi How can we get customer, product details in my Custom module's Index Controller? I have asked here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233255/magento-2-index-controller-display-customer-product-details-on-custom-module

Comment: @Selvamesk, Your link not working!

Comment: @Pallavi Please check the link here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233325/magento-2-custom-order-form-on-product-detailed-page

Comment: if my answer helped, please accept that as answer!

Comment: @Pallavi can you check the above link?

Comment: @Pallavi please check it here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233325/magento-2-custom-order-form-on-product-detailed-page

Comment: I checked that, updated my answer with helper example.

Comment: @Pallavi If I use Model or Helper then how I can get the values from custom form on product page?

Comment: @Selvamesk share your form and helper code here!

Comment: @Pallavi I have posted my entire code here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237401/order-not-creating-magento-2  please check it

Answer (score 1):

For **Mage::getModel** magento1 you need to use the below code for Magento 2:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->create('\Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modulename');
```

For **Mage::getSingleton** you need to use:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->get('\Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modulename');
```

Comment: I need to get all the above values in my custom php file placed in magento 2 root. So let me know how to do this for my above code?

Comment: How can I use it in my Custom class?

Comment: @Selvamesk, Check the link in my answer!

Comment: @Pallavi How can we get customer, product details in my Custom module's Index Controller?

Comment: @Selvamesk, why you need controller for that? you can create model or helper for fetching that data. You will get so many examples in this site for fetching customer/product details. Updated My answer with helper example.

Comment: @Pallavi I think I can't use model or helper because its based on frontend index action. please check this I have asked here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233325/magento-2-custom-order-form-on-product-detailed-page