# How do I run custom script from magento2 root folder?

Tags: custom, script

Below url throwing Class customScript does not exist error. my test.php and customScript.php are in test folder.
Once i run http://127.0.0.1/magento2/test.php, getting "Class customScript does not exist error" .

Here is my test.php code.

```
<?php

  require __DIR__ . '../../app/bootstrap.php';

 $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

 $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('customScript');

$bootstrap->run($app);
```

And in customScript.php

```
<?php

  class customScript extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements 

   \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {

public function launch()
{
    $this->_state->setAreaCode('frontend'); //Set area code 'frontend' or 'adminhtml
    $id = 11588;
    $_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);

    echo $_product->getName();

    return $this->_response;
}

public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
{
    return false;
}


  }
```

[How do I run php custom script on magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97196/how-do-i-run-php-custom-script-on-magento2/97290#97290)

Please anyone able to achieve this?

Comment: paste the content of test.php

Comment: Did you create customScript Class in your test.php?

Comment: No. I have only above code in test.php.

Comment: Ok  what else file you have created?

Comment: I have updated both files.

Comment: Check my answer. Add this line require dirname(__FILE__) . '/customScript.php'; and it works.

Comment: In test.php file? Where?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: hi sukumar, can i call custom controller class to execute on calling url,

Comment: @jafarpinjar Are you able to make it work, am having the same issue

Comment: @Daniel_12, yes it worked for me. use the accepted answer

Comment: What did you do? I am trying but getting 404 or File not found.

Comment: @Daniel_12, update your code with new question, need to check how you are using the solution

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276425/custom-script-leading-to-404-in-m2 here I posted

Comment: @Daniel_12, okay let me check

Comment: @Daniel_12, updated my answer please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you need to use for **test.php**

```
<?php    
require DIR . '../../app/bootstrap.php';
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/customScript.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('customScript');

$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy to Help!

Answer (score 3):

Please try below code to run external script in magento2 :

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params =  $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

echo "test custom script";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to run a custom script from Magento 2 root folder

```
<?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

    include('app/bootstrap.php');
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/customScript.php';
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('customScript');

    $bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: shall we execute any class of different modules by including the path?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to run a custom script on Magento 2 root folder.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$securedArea = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$securedArea->register('isSecureArea', true);

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('global');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productCollection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$productCollection 
    ->setPageSize(20) // only get 10 products 
    ->setCurPage(1)  // first page (means limit 0,10)
    ->load(); 

foreach($productCollection as $product){
    echo $sku = $product->getSku();echo "<br>";
        
}
?>
```

If the pub folder is your Magento's root folder then use the following custom script and you need to create it inside pub diectory.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Config\ConfigOptionsListConstants;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$objectManagerFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::createObjectManagerFactory(BP, []);

$objectManager = $objectManagerFactory->create([]);

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productCollection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$productCollection 
    ->setPageSize(20) // only get 10 products 
    ->setCurPage(1)  // first page (means limit 0,10)
    ->load(); 

foreach($productCollection as $product){
    echo $sku = $product->getSku();echo "<br>";
}   
?>
```