# Custom script leading to 404 in M2

Tags: magento2, custom, install-script, application

I want to create a custom script for this I have created folder test on root

and two files inside folder 
index.php , test.php

My index.php Looks like

```
require DIR . '../../app/bootstrap.php';

require dirname(__FILE__) . '/Test.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Test');

$bootstrap->run($app);
```

and Test.php looks like below

```
class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{
    public function launch()
    {
        echo "launched";
        return $this->_response;

    }

    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

But am getting 404 error example.com/test

example.com/test/index.php getting File not found

Answer (score 0):

**Execute Your Custom Script Like This:-**

> **In Browser :-**

```
localhost/yoursite/test/filename.php
```

> **Using Command :-**

```
php -f test/yourfilename.php
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing, you're wrong here:

```
require DIR . '../../app/bootstrap.php';
```

Need to change to

```
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
```

See in `pub/index.php` as a good example.

Full code

test/index.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

require dirname(__FILE__) . '/Test.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Test');

$bootstrap->run($app);
```

test/Test.php

```
<?php

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{
    public function launch()
    {
        echo "launched";
        return $this->_response;

    }

    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code , its a working copy

Move both the files inside test folder in root directory

**test/test.php**

```
<?php    
 require __DIR__ . '../../app/bootstrap.php';
 require dirname(__FILE__) . '/customScript.php';

 $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

 $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('customScript');

$bootstrap->run($app);

?>
```

then **test/customScript.php**

```
 <?php

   class customScript extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements 

 \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {

 public function launch()
{
    $this->_state->setAreaCode('frontend'); //Set area code 'frontend' or 'adminhtml
     $id = 65;//load any product id
     $_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);

      echo $_product->getName();

    return $this->_response;
}

public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
  {
    return false;
  }


}
```

then hit url in browser like below

http://your_site/test/test.php