# Magento2 custom folder php scripts are not being executing 500 error

Tags: magento2, php-7, script, http-error-500, apache2

I have some PHP scripts for creating products using rest api.
All the script are under products_create_factory folder and this folder is in magneto2 root. When I execute a script from that folder from browser `domain/products_create_factory/createproduct.php` scripts gives 500 error.

BUT if I run the script from the console it executes.

Scripts are independent of `app/bootstrap.php` directory (use only rest api).

I have tried also [this option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/169545/72816) even if scripts use only rest api.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try to find the error message.
Try to check you log files 
or set developer mode and in `app/bootstrap.php` re-comment line

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Error message can help you to find your bug

Comment: thanks for writing. I have already tried. I am getting `Internal Server Error
` every time. but I can see my files throw that URL. I had delete also .htaccess file to check but it didn't work. :(