# Execute custom php file outside /pub folder in Magento2 Nginx

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, nginx

I would like to execute a custom php file (required for a validation and scan) on our Magento2 installation. The file however should remain and be located in the main /var/www/html/ folder and not in the /var/www/html/pub/ folder.

I have tried the following in my main vhost configuration but still getting a 404

```
    location /mycustomfile.php {
        try_files $uri $uri/;
        location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Also I have seen to "whitelist" the file in /var/www/html/nginx.conf.sample under:

```
    # PHP entry point for main application
    location ~ 
  
    (index|get|static|report|404|503|health_check|mycustomfile)\.php$ {
```

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:

Okay I figured it out:

```
    location /mycustomfile.php {
        try_files $uri $uri/;
        root /var/www/html;
        location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/194018/1883

Answer (score 0):

Okay nevermind, I figured it out now

```
location /mycustomfile.php {
        try_files $uri $uri/;
        root /var/www/html;
        location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you provide the solution you applied in order to solve the issue and to mark your question as 'accepted' as solution afterwards.

Comment: I did that directly in the first post

Comment: oh, ok, it's a bit confusing since you also added this answer, it would be a better idea to move the solution in this answer and mark it as accepted.